# Is there a way to edit shared text styles in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

Shared styles in Sketch are great, but what if I want to make a global change, like the font family for my H1, H2, etc.?  There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do this in Sketch.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is not possible to do this at this moment but you can use [this](https://gumroad.com/l/sketch-text-styles-manager) plugin to facilitate your workflow. I am working on a new plugin doing this but it is not ready yet.